# ubuntu 14.04 completely freezes during login

Tags: 14.04, kernel, keyboard, login, mouse

I use ubuntu 14.04. I am facing this problem right now. it freezes every time I want to login. ubuntu worked well for 1 year. no key combinations like alt+sysrq+k or alt+sysrq+REISUB are working. I am completely stuck on my login screen. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of things. Are you running proprietary video drivers? What kernel version are you running? Try and boot into recovery from the grub menu or to a previous kernel version and see if you have the same problem. Sorry for submitting an answer but I need more reputation to comment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Boot from the recovery mode (advanced ubuntu options) worked, now I can login. But the first option 'ubuntu' still has the problem. The kernel version is 4.4.0-111-generic. And when I tried to find what video driver I am using, there comes a warning that says- 'you should run this program as super user', and below that a lot of information, but no driver name is there.

Comment: Run command `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` that way we have an idea of what your vga hardware is

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `Ctl + Alt + F1` If F1 doesn't switch you into Command line please try F1 through F6. If this works correctly you should be at the command line login. Go ahead and attempt to login this way, if it does work run your usually `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Related to JesseMP's answer please supply video drivers and kernel info. Video drivers can be found using `lshw -c video` and look for the driver line. Using `uname -rv` you can locate your kernel info.

If you are able to login run the updates and then reboot the machine, try and login.

If this doesn't work let us know what the issue seems to be and we can work from there.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, but the key combination didn't work. I booted from the advanced ubuntu option (recovery mode). The problem still prevails and when I used "lshw -c video" command, it said 'you should run this program as super user', display unclaimed, driver name was not there after configuration, latency=0 and other informations. Now what can I do?